# Python parsing selected area/range of text file

Tags: python, parsing

I want to print the selected part of a text file, `text.txt`, which contains:

```
tickme 1.1(no.3)
lesson1-bases
lesson2-advancedfurther
para:using the dsp signals are sened via a transmitter to conver to analong signals and gets the output in the form of digital signal

tickme 2.2(no.4)
lesson1-basics2
lesson2-advanced4
para:using the DIGITAL signals are sened via a transmitter to conver to analong signals and gets the output in the form of digital signal

tickme 3.3(no.5)
lesson1-bas
lesson2-adv
para:using the dsp signals are sened via a transmitter to conver to analong signals and gets the output in the form of digital signal
```

Here it consists of 3 tick me but I wanted to select a particular tickme 2.2(no.4) where I have to parse the text before start of tickme 3.3(no.5).

So, if "DIGITAL" is in the paragraph, it has to print "lesson1", since it cause ambiguity I wanted to select range of text file.

Output:

```
lesson1-basics2
```

Since it has lesson 1 common for all tick me,**i need to select specific area to parse between tickme2.2(no.4) to tickme 3.3(no.5)** Is there a way to get range for a specific area and parse ?and possibily there will be large amount of data between tick me not same as example.

Problem: It does not select a specific range.

```
searchstring = ""
with open('text.txt','r') as file:

    for line in file:
        if 'tickme' in line:
            searchstring = line
        if searchstring != '':
            if 'DIGITAL' in line:
                print(searchstring)
                print(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the file into batches like so:

with open('txt.txt') as f:
    batches = []

```
t = []
for l in line:
    if 'tickme' in l:
        # Start a new bactch after saving the previous batch 
        if t: batches.apend(t)
        t = [l.strip()]
    else:
        if len(l.strip()) > 1: t.append(l.strip())
```